# How to avoid javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Tags: mysql, spring, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

These are the specifications that I am using in the application

- Spring 4.0.0
- Spring data version 1.10.1.RELEASE
- Aspect-J version 1.8.9
- Spring-Retry version 1.1.2.RELEASE

The problem that I am facing is an exception that is associated with concurrent transactions in spring data.

There are many users logged in to the application at the same time and access one row of a datbase table simultaneously.

Inorder to avoid dirty reads I have used pessimistic locking in the `repository layer`, for example

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Wallet findOne(Long id);
```

and annotated the methods as transactional and annotated the method as `@Retryable` for retrying the method on certain exceptions, as shown below

```
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, noRollbackFor = {LockAcquisitionException.class})
    @Retryable(value = {LockAcquisitionException.class}, maxAttempts = 5)
        public Wallet doOperations() {
          ......
            }
```

When multiple simultaneous hits occur on the above method some exceptions are thrown as follows:

```
2016-08-29 11:39:03 ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions->146] - Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

but I need the transaction to re-execute and not to throw the exception as shown below.

`javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`

How can I make it happen with spring configuration or do I need to have a manual work-around to solve the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably receive the unchecked exception org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException which wraps the LockAquisitionException. And  this is why you get the Rollback

Comment: Thanks, Yes that's the problem exactly! Should I catch the data access exception manually and handle the codes further or is there any library which handles the exceptions and re executes the transaction so that I can plug and play the library?

Comment: Well as I am not sure about the behaviour of @Retryable, you should probably catch PessimisticLockException and manually code the retry. I presume that 'noRollbackFor' could be removed on this way.

Comment: Ok I will try that out,  but is there any other shortcut coz this will take a lot of work around. By the way I will try catching the pessimistic lock for sure, Thanks